Can't get data out of .bag files. Getting unsupported compression type error: lz4
I am trying to get data stored in .bag files on my linux machine using python. I have installed the required libraries however I every time I attempt to do something with the bag file I get an error like so, rosbag.bag.ROSBagException: unsupported compression type: lz4. I have tried this solution as well as installing lz4 but I can't seem to get past this issue. Here is a sample of my code:
import bagpy
import rosbag
from bagpy import bagreader

b = bagreader('my_bag_file.bag')
lsr = b.message_by_topic('/my/topic')
print(lsr)

I have also tried printing the messages this way but also get the same error:
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['chatter', 'numbers']):
    print(msg)
bag.close()

is there something that needs to be installed or am I running my python file incorrectly or is it something else?
Here is the full error message:
error message

Are you sure yu are running the right python version starting your script? Is lz4 installed for this version as well?
